# Make [headstone] a synonym of [grave-marker]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[headstone](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headstone) and [grave-marker](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grave-marker) both exist. [grave-marker](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grave-marker) has more uses and even a  tag wiki description, so I assume we would make [headstone](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headstone) a synonym of [grave-marker](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grave-marker).

Comment: A headstone is at the head of a gravesite.  Often there are footstones at the feed of a gravesite.  Generally, when that is true, the headstone will have just the last name and the footstones will have first names and birth/death dates.

Comment: @Jeni I've never heard of that. Interesting.

Comment: @Jeni, presumably you're talking about the US? I don't think I've ever seen a footstone in England and Wales, although they exist. I have seen stone borders all round the grave, or the whole grave covered by the stone. Wikipedia says that footstones in the UK are for felons/murderers but shows a picture of a row of graves that have footstones, which makes me doubt they know what they're talking about. Either that or the village in question buried an infeasible number of murderers...

Answer (score 2):

Given that the only two uses of [headstone](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headstone) are also tagged with [grave-marker](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grave-marker), the question of synonymity is moot (in both senses). Creating the rule will have no discernible impact (other than preventing future confusion).

Comment: I think the not yet used but inevitable [tag:gravestone] should come into the mix too.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to deal with tag synonyms on an *ad hoc* basis, I suggest a more structured approach.

1. Identify a relevant area from which questions will be drawn.
2. Use a discussion such has occured here to identify "all possible" tags.
3. Arrange those possibilities in a logical hierarchy of specificity.
4. Nominate the appropriate tag for best use on each branch.
5. Make all terms below the selection synonyms.

In the case of funerary recognition, the heierarchy might look like this:
[image]

So if Grave marker is chosen to become [grave-marker](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grave-marker), then all the terms immediately to its right become synonyms. But [plaque](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plaque) would be permitted to refer separately to the naming of cremated remains (for example).

If that decision seems "wrong" then the fault lies in the hierarchy and it should be rearranged to describe the desired logic for the whole area of memorialising ancestors; rather than just adding or subtracting individual tags.

(Note that I am NOT proposing separate tags for all those descriptions of symbols. It just so happens that the mind-mapping program allocated a style that resembles tags.)

Comment: I agree we need a structured approach -- I think it needs to be a top down structure. We can't answer this question until we've addressed some more fundamental ones.

Answer (score 0):

What about Monumental Inscription? How would you include that? It might not be anywhere near the grave.

Comment: That's different. Is there even a tag for that?

Comment: @JustinY No, but I'd use MI for all three... Not entirely sure what the difference between headstone and grave-marker would be?

Comment: I'm actually incubating a post on our tagging approach -- a sort of overview of where we are and what sort of structure is emerging.

Comment: If the inscription is not near the grave it is a cenotaph. A cenotaph is a monument that is not at the grave site. (I've been spending my 'free' time on Find-A-Grave lately)

Comment: @Jeni, in England and Wales, everyone would think of The Cenotaph in Whitehall if you said cenotaph. All towns and villages (except the Thankful Villages) have War Memorials e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Down_Ampney_war_memorial_-_geograph.org.uk_-_353575.jpg. Any inscription on a gravestone or on a plaque in a church would be a Memorial Inscription.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Was your switch from *Monumental* Inscription in the answer to *Memorial* Inscription in the comment deliberate? If so, what are the implications?

Comment: @Fortiter, no significance -- just me being careless. I meant Monumental Inscription, I think this is one of those differences in terminology between UK and USA -- would be interested to know what's used in Australia.

Comment: I generally use 'gravestone' but that may be more South Australian than east coast.  I have not previously come across Monumental Inscription but can see that for War Memorials, statues, etc it would apply - but I think the actual place of interment should have a distinct tag.

Comment: From a *research guide* published by the National Library of Australia --- There are two main types of cemetery records:
Monumental Inscriptions - listings of gravemarkers, memorial plaques or church monuments that contain a memorial to the dead. Burial registers - sometimes known as burial records or undertakers' records, these are a more comprehensive listing of burials for a particular cemetery

Comment: @Fortiter, that's the classification I'm familiar with.