# Tag cleanup: baptisms and marriages

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This morning I cleaned up the various burial-related tags as per the consensus on [Even more tag cleanup: burials and cemeteries](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2098/even-more-tag-cleanup-burials-and-cemeteries). Part of this process involved renaming [burial](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burial) to [burial-practices](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burial-practices). This was done in the interest of distinguishing questions about burial practices from those about burial records (which are tagged [burial-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burial-records)).

This is a proposal to perform a similar change for two other event tags. Specifically:

- rename [baptism](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism) to [baptism-practices](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism-practices): For questions about customs and traditions associated with baptism or christening.
- rename [marriage](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage) to [marriage-practices](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-practices): For questions about customs, traditions, and laws associated with marriage.

We would keep:

- [baptism-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baptism-records): For questions about finding or interpreting records of baptisms or christenings, such as parish registers or baptism certificates.
- [marriage-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-records): For questions about finding or interpreting records of marriage, such as marriage certificates, registers, indexes, marriage licenses, *banns**, records of dowries and marriage taxes.

The goal is for these tags to have unambiguous names such that the average user can easily know which tag to use.

Any comments or critiques on the proposed names of these tags or their usages?

---

* <sub>Added as per [@JanMurphy's suggestion](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3199/)</sub>

Comment: [tag:baptism-practices] and [tag:marriage-practices] tags created

Answer (score 4):

For [marriage-records](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marriage-records) add 'banns' to the list of types of marriage records.

I like this and think it will add more clarity.